# Get a variable from a class that inherits another

Tags: c#, inheritance

I have an arbitrary amount of classes, `classThatInherits`, `anotherClassThatInherits`, etc. that inherit `classToBeInherited`.
I then have a method, `b`, that needs to be able to access `myValue` from the classes that inherit `classToBeInherited`. How can I achieve this, without casting?

```
//This class will be inherited by other classes
public class classToBeInherited {
    public bool isSomething { get; set; }
}

//This class with inherit 'classToBeInherited'
public class classThatInherits : classToBeInherited {
    public int myValue { get; set; } //this needs to be accessable...
}

//...And so will this class
public class anotherClassThatInherits : classToBeInherited {
    public int myValue { get; set; }
}

private class normalClass {

    private void a() {
        classThatInherits cti = new classThatInherits();
        b(cti);

        anotherClassThatInherits acti = new anotherClassThatInherits();
        b(acti);
    }

    private void b(classToBeInherited c) {
        //***
        //get myValue from the classes that inherit classToBeInherited
        //***
    }
}
```

Comment: Out of curiosity, is there a reason why myValue cannot be a member of the classToBeInherited? Since function b() expects an argument of type classToBeInherited it seems that myValue should be part of that type.

Comment: Well, if classThatInherits can access it that would be fine...

Comment: Yes. Any inherited class can access the public properties of the parent class. So I also think what you have to do is declaring myValue in the classToBeInherited. Any functional restriction not to do so? If not you have to have casting to get that done.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Move `myValue` to `classToBeInherited`:

```
public class classToBeInherited {
    public bool isSomething { get; set; }
    public abstract int myValue { get; set; }
}
```

Then in `classThatInherits` and `anotherClassThatInherits` use `public override int myValue { get; set; }` to implement that property.

Ofcorse, if `myValue` is needed in only some of the classes, then you can have `virtual` and not `abstract` property.

Comment: Thank you so much! setting it to abstract is exactly what i needed.

Answer (score 0):

```
var a = c as anotherClassThatInherits;
if (a != null)
{
    var myValue = a.myValue;
}
```

I don't know why you don't want to do casting, but it's very common to have code like above.

---

**UPDATED**

If you really don't want casting, you can use `reflection` (but you still need to know the type of `anotherClassThatInherits`)

```
var getter = typeof(anotherClassThatInherits).GetProperty("myValue").GetGetMethod();
var myValue = getter.Invoke(c,  null);
```

Comment: No, this wont work for me. void b needs to have no idea of the classes that inherit.

Comment: @bwoogie: I don't think of anyway that makes `void b need to have no idea of the classes that inherit`, but if you want to avoid casting, you can use reflection. See my updated answer